# Pushing to a non-origin non-bare git repository

Tags: git, repository, staging, demo

I have a central, bare, git repository which all of our developers push to. This is our origin. I use origin to push to a separate, non-bare, repository and overwrite all changes. This is intended to be a demonstration area, so we can immediately see changes when somebody pushes to a specific branch.

Origin will push to the demo repository, but the working files are not changed. I have a post-receive hook on origin that calls:

```
git push -f ssh://git@<host>/<path> <branch name>
```

Then my post-receive hook on the demo repo calls:

```
git fetch origin <branch name>
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

If I call those commands on the demo box, my working copy updates fine. But calling them from the post-receive (on the demo repo) leaves changes which need to be manually committed. I want to skip the step where I manually update the working copy.

I realize, through some google-fu and stackoverflow searching, that it's generally bad practice to push to a non-bare repository. I understand the risks, but I'd like this to work, since we use a bare repository for our origin.

Does git do some kind of extra check to prevent the working copy from being updated by the post-receive? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this right, which will solve your problem too:

1. Separate the working site to a bare git repo and to a working dir, let's call them `/repos/demo.git` and `/sites/demo`, respectively
2. Push to your demo repo as usual, that part is fine
3. In the post-receive hook of the demo repo, update the working dir with:

   ```
   git --work-tree /sites/demo reset --hard branchname
   ```

   where `branchname` is the name of the branch that was received (that you pushed)

This way you will not violate good practices: your demo repo is bare, so it's perfectly normal to push to it. There is no `git fetch` step, it's unnecessary, since the demo repo has just received the commits, there's nothing to fetch.

The `--work-tree` is of course the main trick here. It makes git commands manipulate a directory at a different place, and you can use this with bare repositories too. Inside the hook, I think the directory of the bare git repo is correctly set. If not, you can force it with the `--git-dir` option:

```
git --git-dir /repos/demo.git --work-tree /sites/demo reset --hard branchname
```

Comment: That was it, thanks so much for the help. We are running an older version of git, so I cannot init a repo with a separate working tree. I may manually move the working tree so we have a bare repo as you described. Still, specifying the '--work-tree' option was exactly what I was missing. Thanks!